# remove all of a contour from image

Tags: opencv, contour

I need to remove small parts from a binary image. So I find its contours by findContour. Then I find the area of each contour by contourArea. Is there a function that paints all pixels on boundaries and within those contours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cvDrawContours( image, contour, 255, 255, 0, CV_FILLED );

Answer (score 1):

Or, rather, since you're using the OpenCV 2.x API:
drawContours(image, contours, contourIdx, Scalar(255,255,255))

See the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#cv.DrawContours) for more info.